# AngularJs array inside of array display in textarea

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have this kind of data

```
$scope.data = [{
  "production_list": [
    {"product": "google\n"},
    {"product": "stackoverflow\n"},
    {"product": "angular\n"}
   ]
}]
```

How can I display it in textarea like this?

```
<textarea>
  google
  stackoverflow
  angular
</textarea>
```

What I tried is

```
<tr ng-repeat="list in data">
  <td>
    <textarea ng-repeat="x in data.production_list">
       {{x.product}}
    </textarea>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The output is

```
<textarea>
  google
</textarea>
<textarea>
  stackoverflow
</textarea>
<textarea>
  angular
</textarea>
```

And is this a possible to have an increment? Because instead of ng-repeat its better to make it like this

```
<textarea value="data.production_list[$index].product">
</textarea>
```

however $index is not working its value is 0

Comment: do you need two way binding here or simple one time binding

Comment: @jitender can you give me an example sir?

Comment: Mean do you want to change the values inside controller also if you made any change in textarea or you want to simple  display them in textarea?

Comment: Just display in textarea

Comment: ok check my answer then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of writing it as a scope function you can make use of filter so that you can easily re-use code across module.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('joinAttrs', function() {
    return function(list, attrName) {
        var joinedStr = "";
        for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
          joinedStr += list[i][attrName];
        }
        return joinedStr;
    };
});
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{
      "production_list": [
        {"product": "google\n"},
        {"product": "stackoverflow\n"},
        {"product": "angular\n"}
       ]
    }]
});
```

```css
textarea {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="list in data">
    <textarea>{{list.production_list | joinAttrs:'product'}}</textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function that joins the data from the array first, then use that as your `ng-model`.

In your controller:

```
 $scope.textareaData = data[0].production_list
  .map(function(item) {
    return item.product;
  })
  .join('');
```

Then your textarea would be:

```
<textarea ng-model="textareaData"></textarea>
```

This will output each product inside your `textarea`.

Comment: what would happen if there are multiple object inside data?

Comment: I guess it would depend on their data structure. Right now, it is just an object wrapped in an array, so we the `production_list` is at position 0.

Comment: yup it should just wanted to suggest you to give a flexible answer

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Create an function inside your controller and use it in text area something like

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope, $timeout) {
$scope.data = [{
  "production_list": [
    {"product": "google\n"},
    {"product": "stackoverflow\n"},
    {"product": "angular\n"}
   ]
}]
$scope.textAreaValues = function(data){
  var retVal=  data.reduce(function(a,b){
  return {product: a.product + b.product};
  });
  return retVal.product;
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="list in data">
  <td>
    <textarea>
     {{textAreaValues(list.production_list)}}
    </textarea>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```